# MySQL Insert error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Ok, when trying to insert into the database I'm getting this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '@email.com,
>   UT, 84505, NOW(), 69.169.186.192)' at
>   line 1"

I can't figure out the problem. Here is the code for my insert statement.

```
$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email, state, zip, date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
                        $fname,
                        $lname,
                        $email,
                        $state,
                        $zip,
                        $ip);


$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

My table has the following structure:

```
    id int(11)                              
    first_name  varchar(100)                                 
    last_name   varchar(100)                             
    email   varchar(100)                                 
    state   varchar(3)                               
    zip int(10)                             
    date    datetime                                
    ip  varchar(255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote all the string-type columns in the insert statement. Replace `%s` with `'%s'` in the sprintf format.

Please read about SQL Injection if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Beautiful. That did the trick. Earlier in my code I'm using mysql_real_escape_string() on each of the variables. Is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help. I'm new to this whole programming thing. I'll read up more on SQL injection so I don't make this mistake again and keep my sites safe! I appreciate the quick responses from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could echo out the $insert_query, but it looks like you're not putting quotes around the parameters that are varchars.

```
$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email, state, zip, date, ip) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', NOW(), '%s')",
                        $fname,
                        $lname,
                        $email,
                        $state,
                        $zip,
                        $ip);
```

By the way, you have an extra column in your insert - NOW doesn't appear related to a column.
I'm assuming ZIP is a varchar column, not a number, by the way.

Comment: This is the echo of $insert_query

INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email, state, zip, date, ip) VALUES (you, me, a@a.com, AL, 12345, NOW(), 69.169.186.192)

Comment: Yeah, you need to do what Mat suggests. Will edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: Yes it is a varchar, you are right. And that fixed the error I was getting. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO contacts set first_name = '$fname', last_name = '$lname', email = '$email', state = '$state', zip = '$zip', date = ". time() .", ip = '$ip')";


$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

if you want to check query

```
echo $insert_query;
```